# How to add Signup and Sign-In on Agora.io?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, agora.io

How to add `sign-in` or `sign-up` in Agora.io?

Is there any API to add `sign-up` and `sign-in` feature in Agora.io? I want to include this in my android project.

Comment: Do you mean Auth/Auth 2.0 ? If then, the anwser is no.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function for authentication/ storage of user data with Agora.io. It is a Realtime communication as a service platform.